# In which order are packages upgraded when using apt-get upgrade?

Tags: apt

I was always wondering in which order packages are upgraded when running the command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Is is A-Z or just randomly?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the order is neither alphabetical nor random because those methods are not very "intelligent". I believe a more detailed answer would be found in the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/index.html). If I can find the clear answer I will post as an answer, but this may help for now.